# Menu Items are not getting displayed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I implemented WL.OptionsMenu in android environment as specified in Worklight APIs(android/js/mainApp.js). If menu option is clicked, I've given a callback function . Its working fine if the callback resides in the same file. But the implementation of that callback is resided in android/native/common/js/mainApp.js file. Hence, its not showing the menuOptions in android mobile. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your question with the contents of mainApp.js

There is no such path, in Worklight, as android/native/common/js/mainApp.js.
Perhaps you mean android/native/assets/www/default/common/js/mainApp.js, but then again, it is  exactly the same as android/js/mainApp.js.

The only difference is that android/native/assets/www/default/common/js/mainApp.js is created after you build your application.

There is no reason why it should not work.
Again, edit your question with the contents of mainApp.js and the steps you have taken from creating the project, to running it in your device/emulator.